# How to remove data-equalizer-watch tag from this div by using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to remove data-equalizer-watch tag from this div by using jquery

```
<div class="row" style="position:relative; height:784px;" data-equalizer-watch="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use [`removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

```
$('[data-equalizer-watch]').removeAttr('data-equalizer-watch')
```

Comment: thanks for helping, I removed that data watch by using removeAttr. but the problem is that data watch thing already executed, I want to stop that data equalizer watch execute when the page load. do you have any suggestion how can i stop it

Comment: Make sure you do it before loading whatever library or script that uses it

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(something).removeAttr("data-equalizer-watch")
```

see: [JQuery documentation on api function removeAttr](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional class to your `div` like:

```
<div class="row other" style="..." data-equalizer-watch="">...</div>`
```

and from jquery do this: `$('.other').removeAttr('data-equalizer-watch');`

If you want, you can also use an event listener like:

**HTML**:

```
<button id="btn">Remove Equalizer</button>
```

---

**JavaScript (jQyery):**

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    $('.other').removeAttr('data-equalizer-watch');
});
```